# Custom notification is not shown when using `startForeground` on Android O

Tags: android

I want to run background location service. It works more or less, however - instead of my custom notification with text and content intent, generic notification is shown. Why is that?

I am using Nexus API 28 emulator.

Service starting method:

```
private void moveToRunningState() {
    Intent serviceStartIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    int requestId = 1;
    Intent goToMainScreenIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    serviceStartIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent onTapIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), requestId, goToMainScreenIntent, 0);

    Notification.Builder builder = NotificationUtils.notificationBuilderO(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Location tracking is running");
    builder.setContentText("Your location is beeing sent to the server so it can be shown on map");
    builder.setFullScreenIntent(onTapIntent, true);
    builder.setProgress(0,100,true);

    if (NotificationUtils.isPreAndroidO()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "moveToStartedState: Running on Android N or lower - startService(intent)");
        startService(serviceStartIntent);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "moveToStartedState: Running on Android O - startForegroundService(intent)");
        startForegroundService(serviceStartIntent);
    }

    startForeground(1, builder.build());
    Log.i(TAG, "Service moved to start state");
    isRunning = true;
}
```

Just in case, builder creation

```
public static Notification.Builder notificationBuilderO(Context ctx) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Geoloc channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ctx, notificationChannel.getId());
    return builder;
```

and actual result:

[image]

Comment: Offtopic: I would not recommend creating a new notification channel id on each creation. They will show up in the System App Info individually. Define a constant notification channel id.

Comment: Ty, will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I had to post question on SO only to find answer myself seconds afterwards.

The problem is, that I am not setting notification icon. I have tried to show the same notification using `NotificationManager` and it failed with explainatory exception saying that this icon is not set. This exception is not shown in logs in my case when using `startForeground`

All in all, setting icon fixes the issue.